# How to consume message from ActiveMQ with Python

Tags: python, activemq-classic, stomp

I am needing to write a Python script that can consume messages inside ActiveMQ's DLQ queue. This script will continuously run and consume messages in the DLQ queue when there are messages in the queue. The script I wrote is as below. I am facing the problem that when the script runs no message is printed and the script also exits immediately. I want the script that I write to run continuously and print the message to the console

```
import stomp

class MsgListener(stomp.ConnectionListener):
    def __init__(self):
        self.msg_recieved = 0
    def on_error(self, message):
        print('Received the error:' + message)
    
    def on_message(self, message):
        print('Received the error:' + message)
        self.msg_recieved +=1

host = [('10.84.5.10', 61613)]
conn = stomp.Connection(host_and_ports=host)
conn.set_listener('listener', MsgListener())
conn.connect('admin','admin', wait=True)
conn.subscribe(destination='/queue/ActiveMQ.DLQ',id=1, headers={})
```

Comment: Any feedback here? Did my answer address your question?

Answer (score 0):

Your script is exiting immediately after you call `conn.subscribe` which gives no time to actually receive any messages. Remember, the listener is *asynchronous* so there is nothing to block the script from just ending. If you want the script to run continuously then you can do something like this:

```py
import stomp

class MsgListener(stomp.ConnectionListener):
    def __init__(self):
        self.msg_recieved = 0
    def on_error(self, message):
        print('Received the error:' + message)
    
    def on_message(self, message):
        print('Received the error:' + message)
        self.msg_recieved +=1

host = [('10.84.5.10', 61613)]
conn = stomp.Connection(host_and_ports=host)
conn.set_listener('listener', MsgListener())
conn.connect('admin','admin', wait=True)
conn.subscribe(destination='/queue/ActiveMQ.DLQ',id=1, headers={})

while True:
    pass
```